# Is there a way to pickup iPhone calls on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have my iPhone headset plugged into my Macbook Pro so that I can listen to some proper music and have my Iphone 4 lying next to my MB Pro.

Now, of course, it would be really *really* fancy if there was a way I could proxy my incoming iPhone calls to my MB Pro via Bluetooth (essentially turning my MB Pro into a bluetooth headset) so that I can still pick up calls with my iPhone headset, even though it is plugged into my MB Pro.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature apple brought with the lastest OS X : OS X Yosemite.

OS X Yosemite is still a beta and will be released publicly in fall 2014.

Answer (score 3):

As of June 2011, [BluePhoneElite](http://mirasoftware.com/BPE2/) was providing this feature, supporting a great range of mobile phones, but it became abandonware! :(

Their website is suggesting [Phone Amego](http://www.sustworks.com/pa_guide/index.html) as an alternative. It may worth to check it out.

Comment: I checked out Phone Amego, but found it to be *really* poorly designed software, almost to the state that it is unusable. The interface is really lacking and I have not actually gotten it to work as well. Thanks for the tip, though!