# Can a MacBook act as bluetooth headset?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

Is it possible to use my MacBook as a bluetooth headset? I would like to connect my phone to my MacBook via bluetooth, so that when calls or SMS come into my phone I get notified on my MacBook, and ideally be able to read the SMS and reply, and talk and listen to the calls through my MacBook.

Is this possible using bluetooth? Or even better using WiFi?

Comment: This used to be a feature of Apple's Address Book application, but it was removed as of Mac OS X 10.5

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16099/is-there-a-way-to-pickup-iphone-calls-on-my-macbook-pro/

Comment: And in 2015 still there isn't much of options to this.

With Yosemite they support this integration between OSX and iOS but none for Android :/

Still Phone Amego seems to take some time to "upgrade it" in Mavericks, so I have read it...

Answer (score 4):

Get [Phone Amego](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-amego/id405497904?mt=12) from the Mac AppStore. I was looking for the same thing this morning and it worked great! It was very easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. There is an app called BluePhoneElite. With it, you can receive and send call, sms. You can even import and save your call lists and sms.

But it was discontinued. You can get it at Softpedia.

http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Communications/BluePhoneElite.shtml

Comment: We delete answers that are "did you search on [google|youtube|whatever]" since that's not helpful. Can you please edit your question to include relevant links instead.

Comment: But as the product was discounted, I am not sure whether the app will work with iOS. The phones supported were WM and Symbian at that time. I have added a link to download.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I've heard that [Phonecall Wizard](http://www.sustworks.com/pa_guide/index.html#.USpTyL-zefQ) can do this from a thread  on Apple Support Communities: [Can my Mac act as a Bluetooth headset?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3021829?start=0&tstart=0)

As for over Wi-Fi...I doubt it. For Android, it wouldn't be too hard to make such an application, but I failed to find one. For iOS, there's no chance when you consider Apple's strict guidelines for App Store applications.

Comment: the Phonecall Wizard link redirects to a page where talks about Phone Amego... this could have change on all this years?

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for this for the new Nokia 3310, and got to find [HandsFree 2](https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/handsfree2/) which worked.

Though Phone Amigo works, but don't seem stable and quite expensive.

Comment: HandsFree 2 used to work great. Unfortunately, they sold it to a 3rd party and it's no longer available :(